# Two different generated contents at once with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have HTML like this:

```
<body>
<a href="http://foo.xx">bar</a>
</body>
```

Now, I want to add "¹" as content after all links to foo.xx **and** I also want to add "¹ bla" at the end of the text, but only, when there is a link to foo.xx inside. How can I do both? The number of links is not the same in all files: Sometimes there aren't any, sometimes there is only one such link, sometimes many.

The 1st part seems to be easy:

```
a[href*="foo.xx"]:after {content:"¹"}
```

The 2nd part is easy, too:

```
a[href*="foo.xx"]:after {content:"¹ bla"; position:absolute; bottom:0}
```

But how can I get both? For the 2nd part, I tried body:after also, but wasn't able to combine this with the link.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: The "2nd part" doesn't do what you appear to be asking (i.e., add that content after the text), unless they are both supposed to come after the text of the link only, in which case you'd end up with "¹¹ bla" after every link to foo.xx. If you want to do what you're asking, you'd have to use JavaScript, or some kind of server-side language.

Comment: Use your page editor instead. `cntrl+h` on komodo.

Comment: Lol this is easy, use `:before` for second. `a[href*="foo.xx"]:before {content:"¹ bla"; position:absolute; bottom:0}`. Its not an elegant solution though. You should do it with Javascript.